# python regex keep only words that start with alphabet and continues with [a-zA-Z0-9]

Tags: python, regex

Given this text "hey a2a 3beauty hou\se heyYou2", I would like to keep only words that start with alphabeth and continue with a-z, or A-Z, or numbers. So this would be my desired output: " hey a2a heyYou2".

My solution so far passes through text.split() function:

```
text = "hey a2a 3beauty hou\se heyYou2"
text = text.split()
text = [w for w in text if re.search(r"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$", w) is not None]
' '.join(text)

Out[55]: 'hey a2a heyYou2'
```

Is there a fast, more efficient, way I can achieve this using regex, without splitting the text into a list of words?

Comment: `re.sub(r'\s*(?<!\S)(?![a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?!\S))\S+', '', text)`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TTQLCJ/1), [code](https://ideone.com/QkVlEs).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. This will be faster than my solution right?

Comment: No idea, it does not have to be faster, please feel free to test.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you tell me best resource to be good at regex

Comment: @pyd You are already here, at SO :) Watch the regex tag every day, try to solve the problems.

Comment: @Wiktor: I tested them (repeating 10000 times, with cProfile). Your solution is faster (0.029 secs vs 0.039 on Windows, big RAM and CPU). Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I will post then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a single `re.sub` call with the following regex:

```
\s*(?<!\S)(?![a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?!\S))\S+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TTQLCJ/1)

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<!\S)` - a leading whitespace boundary
- `(?![a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?!\S))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are

  - `[a-zA-Z]` - a letter
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0 or more alphanumeric chars
  - `(?!\S)` - a trailing whitespace boundary
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars

[Python code demo](https://ideone.com/QkVlEs):

```
import re
text = "hey a2a 3beauty hou\se heyYou2"
print(re.sub(r"\s*(?<!\S)(?![a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?!\S))\S+", "", text))
# => hey a2a heyYou2
```

Comment: @ Wiktor ,  you won the battle with re :-) nice one +1